# Outline to polyshape object - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I try to convert an outline to a polyshape object using this code:

```
clc;
clear;

RGB = imread('pillsetc.png');
I = rgb2gray(RGB);
bw = imbinarize(I);
imshow(bw)

bw = bwareaopen(bw,30);
bw = imfill(bw,'holes');
imshow(bw)

[B,L] = bwboundaries(bw,'noholes');

imshow(label2rgb(L, @jet, [.5 .5 .5]))
hold on

for k = 1:length(B)
  outline = B{k};
  plot(outline(:,2), outline(:,1), 'w', 'LineWidth', 2)
end

k=1
outline = B{k};

pgon = polyshape(outline)
plot(pgon)
```

But when I plot it I get in it with different orientation and it produce this error:

```
Warning: Polyshape has duplicate vertices, intersections, or other inconsistencies that may produce inaccurate or unexpected results. Input data has
been modified to create a well-defined polyshape. 
> In polyshape/checkAndSimplify (line 339)
  In polyshape (line 152)
  In polyOut (line 26)
```

How can I solve the mentioned issues (orientation and error)?

Thanks

Comment: Would you please explain about `polyshape`?

Comment: pillsetc.png, built-in  image in Matlab

Comment: yeah, I got it thanks;)

Comment: My Matlab is 2017a so it doesn't have `polyshape` function and the error is `Undefined function or variable 'polyshape'.`. but why you used `pgon = polyshape(outline)` , since by default, the polyshape function splits the boundary into two distinct boundaries in order to create a well-defined polygon. I can't check that but maybe it's better to use `pgon = polyshape(outline(:,2), outline(:,1))` because of `outline` type and its values.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help

Comment: welcome, I hope you solve your problem. sorry I couldn't do anything,thanks.